# What is the Catholic Church's teaching on embryo adoption?

Tags: catholicism

It seems like embryo adoption would be a good thing, given the hundreds of thousands of tiny frozen people in the United States.  I understand the rationale behind the Church being against IVF, but what is the Church's teaching concerning non-biological parents implanting embryos which would otherwise be killed or left frozen (and probably eventually die)?

Should it be avoided, celebrated, condemned, condoned, is it a sin, should we praise others whose conscience guides them to do it or counsel them against it?  Does it change matters if a surrogate bears the child instead of the adoptive mother?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35291/what-is-the-catholic-view-on-frozen-embryos Lol, you actually answered it.

Comment: @grasper, search must be very broken (or I am) because that's a total dupe, I'm gonna put a bounty on your question because my answer is not terribly helpful to me!

Comment: See "[Charitable Surrogacy](http://scholastic.us.to/Charitable%20Surrogacy%20(Fr.%20Ripperger,%20F.S.S.P.).pdf)" by Fr. Chad Ripperger.